Is there a better way of typing big equations than this? IEEEtrans
I am writing a journal in IEEEtrans template. I have multiline equation which
is not able to fit in one column. So, did the following:
\documentclass[final]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

% \overrideIEEEmargins                      
\setlength{\textheight}{237mm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{romannum}
\def\m{\tilde{m}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    m & =  2^{\m} - 1 = 2^4 ( 2^{\m/2 - 2})^2 - 1 = 16 k^2 -1, \label{eq:92} \\
    n & = (2^{2\m - 1} + 2^{3\m/2 -2} - 2^{\m - 2} + 2^{\m/2} + 1) (2^{\m/2} - 1) \nonumber \\
    \begin{split}
        & = \Big( 2^7 (2^{\m/2 - 2})^4 + 2^4 (2^{\m/2 - 2} )^3 - 2^2 (2^{\m/2 - 2})^2 \\
        & \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad + 2^2 \cdot 2^{\m/2 - 2} + 1 \Big)\\
        & \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \times (2^2 \cdot 2^{\m/2 - 2} - 1)\\
        & = (2^7 k^4 + 2^4 k^3 - 2^2 k^2 + 2^2 k + 1) (2^2 k - 1) \\
        & = 2^9 k^5 - 2^6 k^4 - 2^5 k^3 + 20 k^2 - 1.
    \end{split} 
\end{align}
\end{document}

But as you can see in image, my result is not looking nice. In addition to that
equation number (2) of last equation is appearing far below the last equation. Can somebody help me out in finding
a right way of typing my equations?


note you almost never need espstopdf, and you are specifying graphicx and romannum twice

Perhaps

\documentclass[final]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

% \overrideIEEEmargins                      
\setlength{\textheight}{237mm}

\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,amsthm}

\def\m{\tilde{m}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    m & =  2^{\m} - 1 = 2^4 ( 2^{\m/2 - 2})^2 - 1 = 16 k^2 -1, \label{eq:92} \\
    n & = (2^{2\m - 1} + 2^{3\m/2 -2} - 2^{\m - 2} + 2^{\m/2} + 1) (2^{\m/2} - 1) \nonumber \\
      &=
        \begin{multlined}[t]
          \Bigl( 2^7 (2^{\m/2 - 2})^4 + 2^4 (2^{\m/2 - 2} )^3 - 2^2 (2^{\m/2 - 2})^2 \\
          + 2^2 \cdot 2^{\m/2 - 2} + 1 \Bigr) (2^2 \cdot 2^{\m/2 - 2} - 1)
          \end{multlined}\nonumber\\
        & = (2^7 k^4 + 2^4 k^3 - 2^2 k^2 + 2^2 k + 1) (2^2 k - 1) \nonumber\\
        & = 2^9 k^5 - 2^6 k^4 - 2^5 k^3 + 20 k^2 - 1.
\end{align}
\end{document}

I don't think aligning the explicit \times with the + in the inner term helps, and not doing that also saves a line. Also note \Big[lr] not \Big

I don't think it’s “small”.
In the following I added lipsum just to show the formula surrounded by text.
The idea is that the first column in an aligned is flush right, so we can avoid adding space by hand. The aligned is “top aligned”, so its first line is level with the equals sign.
Note also \bigl( and \bigr). You might want \Big size (I wouldn't), but they should be \Bigl( and \Bigr).
\documentclass[final]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

% \overrideIEEEmargins                      
%\setlength{\textheight}{237mm}% don't change the class defaults

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}% not needed
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{romannum}% twice?

\usepackage{lipsum}% to see in context

\newcommand{\m}{\tilde{m}}% not \def

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-3]
\begin{align}
  m & =  2^{\m} - 1 = 2^4 ( 2^{\m/2 - 2})^2 - 1 = 16 k^2 -1, \label{eq:92} \\
  n & = (2^{2\m - 1} + 2^{3\m/2 -2} - 2^{\m - 2} + 2^{\m/2} + 1) (2^{\m/2} - 1) \nonumber \\
    & =  \begin{aligned}[t]
         \bigl( 2^7 (2^{\m/2 - 2})^4 + 2^4 (2^{\m/2 - 2} )^3 - 2^2 (2^{\m/2 - 2})^2 \\
         {}+ 2^2 \cdot 2^{\m/2 - 2} + 1 \bigr)\\
         {} \times (2^2 \cdot 2^{\m/2 - 2} - 1)
         \end{aligned} \nonumber \\
    & = (2^7 k^4 + 2^4 k^3 - 2^2 k^2 + 2^2 k + 1) (2^2 k - 1) \nonumber \\
    & = 2^9 k^5 - 2^6 k^4 - 2^5 k^3 + 20 k^2 - 1.
\end{align}
\lipsum

\end{document}


The same if I add
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

(you need to remove amssymb, the newtx packages cover the symbol set anyway). I recommend it so your math formulas have the same font family as the text.
\documentclass[final]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

% \overrideIEEEmargins                      
%\setlength{\textheight}{237mm}% don't change the class defaults


\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}% not needed
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{romannum}% twice?

\usepackage{lipsum}% to see in context

\newcommand{\m}{\tilde{m}}% not \def

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-3]
\begin{align}
  m & =  2^{\m} - 1 = 2^4 ( 2^{\m/2 - 2})^2 - 1 = 16 k^2 -1, \label{eq:92} \\
  n & = (2^{2\m - 1} + 2^{3\m/2 -2} - 2^{\m - 2} + 2^{\m/2} + 1) (2^{\m/2} - 1) \nonumber \\
    & =  \begin{aligned}[t]
         \bigl( 2^7 (2^{\m/2 - 2})^4 + 2^4 (2^{\m/2 - 2} )^3 - 2^2 (2^{\m/2 - 2})^2 \\
         {}+ 2^2 \cdot 2^{\m/2 - 2} + 1 \bigr)\\
         {} \times (2^2 \cdot 2^{\m/2 - 2} - 1)
         \end{aligned} \nonumber \\
    & = (2^7 k^4 + 2^4 k^3 - 2^2 k^2 + 2^2 k + 1) (2^2 k - 1) \nonumber \\
    & = 2^9 k^5 - 2^6 k^4 - 2^5 k^3 + 20 k^2 - 1.
\end{align}
\lipsum

\end{document}


